# Deregister an event in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, rootscope

Having a controller, MyCtrl:

```
class MyCtrl {
    constructor($scope, $rootScope, ...) {
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
        this.doThis = _debounce(this.resize.bind(this), 300);
        ...
    }
    $onInit() { ... }
    $onDestroy() { ... }
}
```

Inside `$onInit` is called `$rootScope.$on`. Like this one, is another controller with does the same operations but for a different type of page, let's say MyCtrl2. When I go to the second one from the first one, the first one keeps getting called because it is not destroyed. I solved this problem using the method described [Prevent $rootScope.$on from calling function several times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521559/prevent-rootscope-on-from-calling-function-several-times) by adding a deregister. 
The `$onInit` now:

```
$onInit() {
    this.$rootScope.$on('toggleNav', () => {
        this.doThis();
    });
    this.deregisterDoThis = this.$rootScope.$on('listen', function() {
        this.$scope.doThis();
    });
    this.$rootScope.$on('$destroy', this.deregisterDoThis);
}
```

Now, if I go from the first controller's page to the page of the second, everything works fine. BUT, when I click for going back to the page of the first one, there is an error in the console saying:

> ```
>  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
>     at $.t.default [as attr] (vendor.dll.js?aca3f637cd46c07f3280:135)
>     at attachNotes (VM133106 chart-util.js:1016)
>     at invokeFunc (debounce.js?e59c:95)
>     at trailingEdge (debounce.js?e59c:144)
>     at timerExpired (debounce.js?e59c:132)
> ```

Any ideas about this?

Comment: You can use the return value of `$scope.$on` to deregister an event. Refer - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on

Comment: sorry, I don't get it.

Comment: You can try using `$stateChangeSuccess` event to re-bind the `$scope.$on` handler

Comment: try : `this.deregisterDoThis = this.$rootScope.$on('listen', () => { this.$scope.doThis();   });`

Comment: @anoop any other difference than the original except that you are using ES6 syntax ?

Comment: @AdityaBhave: it is important to keep the scope of `this` (can be done by ES6), else it will be null. Further to deregister the event `$destroy` should be enough, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898296/how-to-unsubscribe-to-a-broadcast-event-in-angularjs-how-to-remove-function-reg)

Comment: @anoop, looks like the same thing I did, I tried it anyway, the same error as result =>  run in in ctrl1 - works fine, go to ctrl2 - works fine, go back to ctrl1 - error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$rootScope.$on('$destroy')` is never called because `$rootScope` is never destroyed.

```
$onInit() {
    this.deregisterToggleNav = this.$rootScope.$on('toggleNav', () => {
        this.doThis();
    });
    this.deregisterDoThis = this.$rootScope.$on('listen', ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶)̶ () => {
        ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶d̶o̶T̶h̶i̶s̶(̶)̶;̶
        this.doThis();
    });
    ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶$̶r̶o̶o̶t̶S̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶o̶n̶(̶'̶$̶d̶e̶s̶t̶r̶o̶y̶'̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶d̶e̶r̶e̶g̶i̶s̶t̶e̶r̶D̶o̶T̶h̶i̶s̶)̶;̶
}
```

Instead use the `$onDestroy` Life-cycle Hook:

```
$onDestroy() {
    this.deregisterToggleNav();
    this.deregisterDoThis();
}
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $compile Service API Reference - Life-Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)

Comment: it has the same behavior. shouldn't be made a change in $onDestroy maybe? like set deregisterDoThis() to null or false or something like that